# iOS 8 registerForRemoteNotifications correct implementation placing

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I've seen a ton of different notifications permission request implementations and I still don't know which one is best. This might be a duplicate but I want a **2015** answer that should encase the latest Apple recommendations.

My general question is whether to put the `registerForRemoteNotifications` call immediately before the `registerUserNotificationSettings:` call, immediately after it, or in it's `application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:` delegate method.

Currently, I have it like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

and after testing it on a device *(for the first time, because the user's response to the standard alert is annoyingly cached, even after the app is reinstalled)*, I got this in the console:

```
2015-02-16 16:27:33.025 AppName[2679:591060] NOTIFICATIONS: didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: <XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX>
```

**then** Apple's standard alert showed up, and after choosing *Yes*, I got these in the console:

```
2015-02-16 16:32:26.631 AppName[2679:591060] NOTIFICATIONS: application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:: <UIUserNotificationSettings: 0x174634300; types: (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert UIUserNotificationTypeBadge UIUserNotificationTypeSound);>
2015-02-16 16:32:27.229 AppName[2679:591060] NOTIFICATIONS: didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: <XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX> // same token
```

How did the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` delegate got called before responding to the alert? Is it because the two calls are one after the other?

**Update:**

I made another test in which I chose *No* on the standard alert and I got these in the console:

```
2015-02-16 16:54:37.472 AppName[2717:595759] NOTIFICATIONS: didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: <XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX>
2015-02-16 16:54:44.353 AppName[2717:595759] NOTIFICATIONS: application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:: <UIUserNotificationSettings: 0x174432cc0; types: (none);>
```

so the `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` was **never called**.

How is this possible? It's contrary to Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My general question is whether to put the registerForRemoteNotifications call immediately before the registerUserNotificationSettings: call, immediately after it, or in it's application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings: delegate method.

Did you get a good answer? I believe the right place is in the application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings in the app Delegate. Assuming from above you want to handle all of this in your view controller instead of app Delegate, use an NSNotification in this response and responses to registerForRemoteNotifications and put a corresponding listener in your view controller.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    if (notificationSettings.types != UIUserNotificationTypeNone) {
        //register to receive notifications
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        // same as response to didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
        NSDictionary* data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"" forKey:@"deviceToken"];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationsRegistered" object:self userInfo:data];
    }
}
```

Comment: I left is as in my original post. This might be the good answer but I'm afraid to change anything :)) So I'll mark this as the correct solution for the time.

Answer (score -1):

I usually put the register for notification method inside the applicationDidFinishLauching of the app delegate. The snippet I've posted works for iOS8 and lower. The settings is quite wide and it should be ok if you are not looking for particular customization.

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // iOS 8
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // iOS < 8
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

Once you have successfully obtained your token you can send it to your server.

Comment: Wouldn't this request it immediately after opening the app? Also, the recommended way of testing the availability of methods at run time is `[UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)]`. Firstly, the `instancesRespondToSelector` as shown [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-1114537-BABHHJBC), and secondly, it makes more sense to test for the method that you're going to call.

Comment: Yes this request the registration right after opening the app, about the availability of methods I don't find nothing wrong you can do either way. I'm just asking to the app delegate instance if it can respond to a method that is only implemented in iOS8. The difference is that the apple one is a class method.

Comment: Well, I don't know who would want that when Apple says that _"It is recommended that you call this method before you schedule any local notifications or register with the push notification service."_. And, because for a newcomer is very very confusing finding x different implementation. Isn't it better to just do it the way Apple does?

Comment: I' m sorry but I don't get your point, in applicationDidFinishLauching is impossible that you have already scheduled a notification. You register the settings and later you register for notification. It seems correct.

Comment: Well, if you do this, a very big percent of users will decline it.